# Gazebo 11 does not run

Tags: linux, gazebo-simu

I have installed Gazebo 11 on Ubuntu 20.04 through binary packages. When I launch Gazebo it raises the following error:

```
gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart-collision-bullet.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know what is the problem? I tried to solve the problem installing `libdart-collision-bullet-dev`, but the following problem raises:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdart-collision-bullet-dev : Depends: libdart-dev but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: libdart6-collision-bullet (= 6.9.2-2build4) but 6.9.5-1885~202012292349~ubuntu20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to solve the broken packages, but then Gazebo 11 is automatically uninstalled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is not related to Dart programming language, which [dart] tag is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this is what worked for me.

- First remove and purge all the libdart packages.

```
sudo apt remove --purge libdart*
```

- If you have added `dartsim/ppa` ppa from this [link](https://dartsim.github.io/install_dart_on_ubuntu.html), remove it from **Software & Updates -> Other Software**
- Update

```
sudo apt update
```

- Check if libdart-dev installs with:

```
sudo apt install libdart-dev
```

- If it installs, then install all the packages required for Gazebo

```
sudo apt install libdart-all-dev
```

- If there is an error related to `unable to fetch some archives`, try:

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install libdart-all-dev
```

- Install Gazebo again with:

```
curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

- Check if Gazebo is now working

```
gazebo
```